# SqlDataConnection update method

Tags: sql, f#

I'm using Microsoft's [SqlDataConnection type provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362320.aspx). However, the only way I've seen to update a row in the database is to use something similar to this where it updates mutable values:

```
let updateProduct product = 
  let currentProduct = query {
    for c in context.Product do
    where (c.Product_id = product.ProductId)
    select c } 

let record = currentProduct |> Seq.head

record.Product_name <- product.ProductName
record.Product_count <- Nullable<int>(product.ProductCount)
record.Product_price <- product.ProductPrice

try
    context.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
with
    | ex -> printfn "Error when inserting - %s" ex.Message
```

In case it's needed, I'm using this `Product` type:

```
[<CLIMutable>]
type Product = {
  ProductId: int
  ProductName: string
  ProductCount: int
  ProductPrice: string
}
```

Is there a "more F# way" to handle the update instead of updating the record I find from the database?